# iOS 8: UISlider no longer slides after setting hidesBarsOnSwipe to YES

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, xcode6

I've set...

```
self.navigationController.hidesBarsOnSwipe = YES;
```

I also have a UISlider in a `tableHeaderView`. The UISlider no longer slides when using `hidesBarsOnSwipe`. I assume `hidesBarsOnSwipe` is consuming the gesture that the slider would typically use. To get around this with traditional gesture recognizers you can use...

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
```

to fire more than one gesture at a time. But to get that to work you need to set the delegate, and you are not allowed to change the `barHideOnSwipeGestureRecognizer` delegate.

Any ideas? I'm stumped. Not sure how to get past this.

Comment: This looks like a bug to me. I tried it out, and occasionally I could get the slider to slide, but most of the time not. Same with sliders that I put in the cells themselves.

Comment: I was able to get it working by changing the Top Space constraint of my TableView to the Superview (underneath the navigation bar). Hope this works for you too!